# Do Bloodreavers gain an extra attack from a Bloodsecrator's Rage of Khorne ability?

Tags: age-of-sigmar

In Age of Sigmar, a unit of Bloodreavers has the **KHORNE** keyword and the Frenzied Devotion ability:

> **Frenzied Devotion:** If this unit is within 12" of
>   a **CHAOS TOTEM** from your army when it is
>   selected to attack, then all models in this unit make
>   2 attacks rather than 1, and the Chieftain makes 3
>   attacks rather than 2.

Meanwhile, a Bloodsecrator has the **CHAOS** and **TOTEM** keywords, and has the option of using its Rage of Khorne ability:

> *Rage of Khorne:* This ability affects all **KHORNE** units in your army within 18" of this model at the start of your combat phase. When they attack, add 1 to the Attacks characteristic of all melee weapons used by units affected by the Rage of Khorne. In addition, players do not have to take battleshock tests for any **KHORNE** units within 18" of this model.

With all of this in mind, consider the following scenario:

- In the hero phase, the Bloodsecrator uses its Rage of Khorne ability.
- At the start of the combat phase, a unit of Bloodreavers is within 12" of a Bloodsecrator.
- The unit of Bloodreavers is selected to attack an enemy unit.

In this scenario, **how many attacks does each Bloodreaver make?**

The description of Frenzied Devotion does not mention the Attacks characteristic of the models, and it could be interpreted that the new number of attacks is only gained when the Bloodreavers would make 1 attack (2 in the case of the Bloodreaver Chieftain). However, this would mean that the only benefit the Bloodreavers would gain from the Bloodsecrator's Rage of Khorne ability is not having to take battleshock tests - which seems nonsensical from both a gameplay and flavour perspective.

Answer (score 1):

As with most rules in AoS the simplest solution is usually the correct one and rules stack.

Therefore if you have a unit of BloodReavers:

- within 12" inches of a Bloodsecrator you get 3 attacks
- between 12" and 18" of a Bloodsecrator you get 2 attacks
- over 18" from a Bloodsecrator you get 1 attacks

The Chieftain gets an additional attack on top.

I actually wasn't 100% of this so I asked on [TGA](http://www.tga.community/forums/topic/9939-a-question-about-bloodreaver-attacks/#comment-104814). Here's the quote directly from Killax:

> Frenzied Devotion gives them an additional attack if they are within
>   12" of  Chaos Totem. This ability is not cumulative. The Bloodsecrator
>   has the Chaos Totem Keyword but the Bloodsecrator is not the prime
>   Keyword for Frenzied Devotion to be activated. 
>   - Rage of Khorne is an ability that the Bloodsecrator only has if he 'activates' Portal of Skulls. This is something you have to declare in
>   the Hero phase and not something that continues once you do. This
>   ability is cumulative because it adds 1 to all melee attacks.
>
> So depending on wether the Bloodsecrator has activated the Portal of
>   Skulls or not the Bloodreavers will have two attacks instead of one if
>   they are within 12" of the Chaos Totem (which can be a Bloodsecrator)
>   and depending if the Bloodsecrator has used the Portal of Skulls or
>   not you can add 1 attack in the Combat phase thanks to Rage of Khorne
>   if they are within that range aswell.
>
> The common mistake I see here is:
>
> 1. Frenzied Devotion does not look for Bloodsecrator Keyword but Chaos Totem Keyword.
> 2. Portal of Skulls leads to the Bloodsecrator having the Rage of Khorne ability. It is NOT a permanent ability.